# Ubuntu not showing java is installed

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

I downloaded the .tar.gz of from the offical site and extracted it into `/opt/java` directory and

```
$ ls /opt/java
```

gives

```
jdk-10.0.1
```

but when I run

```
$ java -version
```

it gives

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:


* default-jre
* openjdk-8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.9-jre-headless
* gcj-5-jre-headless
* gcj-6-jre-headless
* openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Why is not showing the version of java jdk installed?

Comment: Because you haven't added that directory to your PATH; and because you didn't install the JDK from the [webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8).

Comment: I tried adding the lines `JAVA_HOME = "/opt/java/jdk-10.0.1"` `export JAVA_HOME` to `/etc/environment` but when I run `source /etc/environment` it gives me `JAVA_HOME: command not found
`

Comment: It would do. You have extra spaces around `=`. Remove those. You'll also need to add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: thanks, didn't knew about the spaces :)

Answer (score 1):

that means java is intalled but it doesn't know where...

you have to set your JAVA path inside: /etc/profile
and must add to that file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<your_java_path>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

you have to replace

```
<your_java_path>
```

for your known current java path